# Abuso de votos negativos

Tags: soporte, votos-negativos

Me he visto obligado a borrar una respuesta correcta a una pregunta que conteste, por que un usuario con suficiente reputación para votar negativo la respondió mas tarde prácticamente igual y voto  negativamente mi respuesta sin motivo alguno.

¿Existe alguna manera de evitar estas prácticas?

Edito:
Error mio, al interpretar lo que paso. 
Link de la pregunta.
[Números reales en c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90100/n%C3%BAmeros-reales-en-c/90105#90105)

Comment: Sería bueno que pusieras un enlace a la pregunta, para que podamos ver el caso mejor. Yo tambien te recomendaría no borrar tu respuesta, si es correcta la comunidad corregirá ese voto negativo

Comment: Bienvenido a Meta Adrian. En Meta no es usual usa las etiquetas dicusción y soporte juntas. Si estás buscando opinión, es decir que no hay una respuesta correcta, se usa la primera, si estas buscando orientación sobre cómo usar el sitio principal o Meta, usa soporte. Más detalles en [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

> Me he visto obligado a borrar una respuesta correcta

Estás seguro que la respuesta era correcta? Es posible que la respuesta fuera correcta, pero que no estuviera correctamente fundamentada/explicada? O que tuviera algún error tipográfico que la invalidara?

> por que un usuario con suficiente reputación para votar negativo la respondió mas tarde prácticamente igual y **voto negativamente mi respuesta**

Como sabes que fue el mismo usuario que respondió posteriormente? Es posible que no fuera el, sino otra persona. Aquí podríamos volver al punto anterior: quizá la respuesta no era tan correcta como piensas.

> Existe alguna manera de evitar estas practicas?

Si te refieres a que alguien añada una respuesta y vote negativamente otra, no es posible. Cada usuario puede votar positiva o negativamente de acorde a su propio criterio (aunque obviamente si ese es el caso, la practica no está recomendada y, como opinión personal, no tiene sentido y es de mala educación)

Pero, y aqui viene lo maravilloso de Stack Overflow en Español...un voto negativo es **solo un voto**. Aunque se puedan producir, y a veces se produzcan, abusos de este tipo, esta comunidad tiene la capacidad de corregir estas situaciones **mediante la votación de otros miembros**. En tu caso, al eliminar la respuesta no podemos hacer nada, pero si no la hubieras eliminado otros usuarios podrían haber visto que tu respuesta era correcta y,en ese caso, haber votado positívamente corrigiendo de esta manera la situación.

Mi recomendación es que si estás seguro de la validez de la respuesta, no la elimines. Cualquier puntuación negativa puede ser finalmente corregida.

---

> la respondió mas tarde

Tras consultar el historial de la pregunta, se aprecia que esto no es así, el otro usuario contesto antes que tu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: he recuperado la respuesta

Comment: @AdrianGodoy bueno...tu respuesta tal como está ahora mismo es correcta, pero viéndola antes de la edición, a pesar de ser también correcta es un código no muy elegante. Con lo que pudo haber gente que la puntuó negativo por esa razón, o pudo considerar que tener que hacer un casting era innecesario pudiendo definir las variables directamente como `double`... Como te digo, cada uno es libre de votar por sus propias razones y no ha tenido por que ser el otro usuario que también respondió, de hecho tienes dos votos negativos.

Comment: había 2 respuestas  muy parecidas, y cuando apareció la aceptada, ambas recibimos el negativo.  Se que no puedo estar 100% seguro, pero pareció que paso eso. La verdad es que desanima mucho ver tu reputación en 0 por cosas así.

Comment: Por cierto @AdrianGodoy ,ahora que reviso, la respuesta de Alejandro Ricotti es anterior a la tuya (en 8 minutos concretamente). Eso ha podido granjearte negativos tambien :)

Comment: Como offtopic, también se aprecia la velocidad de @lois6b en sus ediciones :)

Comment: @Pikoh ;) el más rapido del oeste :D